How to remove duplicated migration having same content in django
if we created a procedure in django project and then we need to changed variables or any changes in content. then same named procedure duplicates . we need to remove it
0002_remove_whocanapprove_approver_level_and_more
0004_remove_whocanapprove_approver_level_and_more
this 2 are same then remove first one

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

def extract_sql_content(filepath):
"""Extract the SQL content from a migration file."""
try:
with open(filepath, "r") as f:
content = f.read()
match = SQL_PATTERN.search(content)
if match:
return match.group(
0
)  # Return the SQL function definition line
except Exception as e:
print(f"Error reading file {filepath}: {e}")
return None
def get_migration_files(directory):
"""Return a list of migration files in the directory."""
return [
f for f in os.listdir(directory) if FILE_PATTERN.match(f)
]
def group_by_sql_content(migration_files):
content_groups = defaultdict(list)
for filename in migration_files:
    filepath = os.path.join(DIR, filename)
    sql_content = extract_sql_content(filepath)
    if sql_content:
        content_groups[sql_content].append(filename)
return content_groups

def keep_latest_and_remove_others(content_groups):
for files in content_groups.values():
    if len(files) > 1:
        
        files.sort(reverse=True)
        for old_file in files[1:]:
            old_file_path = os.path.join(DIR, old_file)
            try:
                os.remove(old_file_path)
                print(f"Removed: {old_file}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error removing file {old_file}: {e}")

def main():
migration_files = get_migration_files(DIR)

content_groups = group_by_sql_content(migration_files)

keep_latest_and_remove_others(content_groups)

if name == "main":
main()

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
